# Grep from a certificate

Tags: grep, certificate

I can view the openSSL certifcate with this command

```
openssl x509 -text -in myCertificate.pem
```

I just wanted to see when the cert will expire only.  The line which I want to read is,
 **Not After : Jul 28 14:09:57 2015 GMT**
I tried using the grep command but it doesn't display anything.

```
grep "After" myCertificate.pem
```

Is there a way that I can read only that line of the certificate??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The short way is to use `-enddate -noout` (print the notAfter value, and don't re-output the cert PEM contents)

```
$ openssl x509 -in github.cer -enddate -noout
notAfter=Apr 12 12:00:00 2016 GMT
```

In order to use `grep` you need to continue using the `-text` option, because the phrase "Not After" doesn't appear in the cert, it's just an encoded representation.  And then combine that with the pipe (`|`) operation:

```
$ openssl x509 -in github.cer -text -noout | grep After
            Not After : Apr 12 12:00:00 2016 GMT
```